# How to call a Successful Callback function after executing an Asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have Created a asynchronous method like below

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(
                                        () => AddAttachment(document, docId, user)).ContinueWith(
                                            task => BackUpQueuesMail(task.Exception, information, list),
                                            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

I need to execute a callback function after AddAttachment() methods process successfully. How can i possible this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(
                                        () => AddAttachment(document, docId, user)).ContinueWith(
                                            task => OnComplete(task), }
                                            TaskContinuationOptions.None);  


private void OnComplete(task)
{
   if(task.IsFaulted)
   {
   }
   else if(task.IsComplete) {}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to extract out the AddAttachment task, then you can use [continuation tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx) to specify what task to execute if your main task failed, and what task to execute if the main task completed successfully.

In this sample the *MethodToRunWhenFinishSuccessfully* will run if *AddAttachment* completed and *BackUpQueuesMail* will run in case *AddAttachment* failed.

```
var addAttachmentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddAttachment(document, docId, user));
addAttachmentTask.ContinueWith(t => MethodToRunWhenFinishSuccessfully(t), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
addAttachmentTask.ContinueWith(t => BackUpQueuesMail(task.Exception, information, list), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: You don't need the delayed start. Just use StartNew.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `OnlyOnFaulted` to `OnlyOnRanToCompletion`.